# ASP.NET Globalization: Culture="auto" page directive with neutral culture crash?

Tags: asp.net, globalization, cultureinfo

I'm running into a case where an ASP.NET application using the built-in globalization facilities is crashing.

On an ASP.NET page with the Culture="auto" directive, a user with a neutral culture as their browser language (such as "zh-Hans") will produce the following exception:

> Culture 'zh-Hans' is a neutral culture. It cannot be used in
>   formatting and parsing and therefore
>   cannot be set as the thread's current
>   culture.
>
> at System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CheckNeutral(CultureInfo
>   culture) 
>   at System.Threading.Thread.set_CurrentCulture(CultureInfo
>   value) 
>   at System.Web.UI.Page.set_Culture(String
>   value) 
>   at ASP.somePage_aspx.__BuildControlTree(somePage_aspx __ctrl) 
>   at ASP.somePage_aspx.FrameworkInitialize()

Any ideas? Garbage fed into the Culture/UICulture parameters generally seem to be ignored, but this case is causing an unhandled exception.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First off, you might consider setting UICulture="auto" as well as Culture="auto" in your <%@ Page %> declaration.

Now, I am not seeing this repro on my .NET 4.0 (beta) install, so this might be a product bug in .NET 3.5.

Here's a great resource for learning about neutral cultures and the difference between UICulture and Culture: http://blogs.msdn.com/ddietric/archive/2008/02/05/yacvcp-yet-another-currentculture-vs-currentuiculture-post.aspx

Hope that's helpful.

Answer (score 6):

I was having the same problem and after bonking my head against a wall for a while found the answer right under my nose.

The issue I had was in not understanding the difference between **CurrentCulture** and **CurrentUICulture**. The difference being **CurrentCulture** is used to format dates, numbers and perform sorting, **CurrentUICulture** is used to lookup culture specific strings from a resource.

I had some code that looked like

```
return input.ToString("C", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture);
```

when it should be been

```
return input.ToString("C", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
```

When you start trying to format culture specific items with a non-specific culture you will get the System.NotSupportedException.

Comment: This may not be the exact same problem but you should be looking for some code where you are trying to assign a neutral culture via CurrentUICulture to something expecting a more specific culture that you can access via CurrentCulture.

Answer (score 2):

Can't you set the culture on begin request? (Note: asp.net requests can jump between threads so you need to hook into the thread moving as well.)

Comment: hi Andrew Arnott. i placed culture="auto" uiculture="auto" in my <%@Page %>.Even also getting same exception as Culture 'zh-Hans' is a neutral culture. It cannot be used in formatting and parsing and therefore cannot be set as the thread's current culture. this exception in single page remaining all pages working fine.------Please help me