# Bug in ASP.NET 2.0 when handling browser culture

Tags: asp.net, culture

I have this setting in my web config:

```
<globalization culture="auto" uiCulture="auto"/>
```

The code is compiled in  VS 2010.

If target platform is set to .NET 2.0 or 3.0 then it only works for IE and I get this error on Chrome

> "Culture 'es' is a neutral culture. It cannot be used in formatting
>   and parsing and therefore cannot be set as the thread's current
>   culture."

If target platform is .NET 4.0, it works for both IE and Chrome.

Is this a bug in ASP.NET 2.0/3.0? Is there a fix for it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up using CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture.  It works most of the times.

.NET 4 allows setting neutral culture for formatting. It picks the culture with the most population for that language, that's what I heard.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like it might be a bug.  Could you post the stack trace?

You also might try looking at the Accept-Language header sent by the two browsers, using a tool such as Fiddler, to understand the difference.

Note that with IE, you can control what is sent in the Accept-Language header.  Simply open IE and in Tools / Internet Options / General, click on the Languages button.  Click on Add and e.g. add a custom language "es", and move it to the top of the list.

**UPDATE**

It sounds similar to [the problem described in this StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1314627/asp-net-globalization-culture-auto-page-directive-with-neutral-culture-crash).

The stack trace in that question shows that the exception is thrown in the Page.Culture property setter.  I'd say it is a bug; and probably fixed in recent versions of the Framework (I can't reproduce it with .NET 3.5 and the latest service packs).

Comment: The exception is thrown for this line:

Culture c = System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture

Chrome sends "es,en-US;q=0.8" in the Accept-Language header while IE sends "es-MX,es;q=0.8". 

I added the custom language (es) in IE and the problem shows up too.